# Delete QMGR associated with a different installation (exitvalue=62)

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I installed a `WAS MQ 7.0` on linux then create some QMGRs there.
After a while I decide to use `WAS MQ 7.5` for security reasons. Then I unistall version 7.0 and install version 7.5. 
In 7.5 I want to delete all QMGRs that I created in version 7.0, So I try to delete those QMGR but I face to this error:

```
Queue manager 'X' is associated with a different 
installation ('installation0') exitvalue=62
```

How can I delete this queue manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associate MQ v7.0 queue managers to MQ v7.5 using `setmqm` command and then delete.

```
SETMQM -m <qm> -n <mqv75 installation name>
```

Comment: When I run this, I get:

AMQ5687: setmqm is not executing from installation 'Installation0'. Any ideas why?

Comment: It appears that you have multiple MQ installations. You have to run the setmqm command from the installation to which you want to associate a queue manager. Basically in a command shell, change directory to the /bin directory of the installation and then run the setmqm command.